# Потеря точности C++

Tags: c++

При тестировании программы был получен результат:
Ввод - значение
9.995 - 9.99 (вместо 10.00)
0.995 - 1.00
152.995 - 153.0
7.895 - 7.89 (вместо 7.90)
Далее приведен исходный текст программы:

1ый файл

```
int main()  {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
double n,rub,cop;
cout << "Преобразование числа в денежный формат." << "\n";
cout << "Введите дробное число - "; cin >> n;
cop = modf(n, &rub);
cop = roadcent(cop);
if (cop == 100) { 
    cop = 0;
    ++rub;
}
cout << n << "руб. - это " << rub << " руб. " << cop << " коп." << "\n";
system("pause");
return 0;  }
```

2ой файл

```
double roadcent(double k) {
k *= 100;
int l = (int)(k * 10) % 10;
if (l == 5) { return floor(k + 1); }
else { return floor(k + 0.5); } }
```

С чем связан полученный результат? Какие есть варианты исправления данной погрешности?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Проблема, разумеется, в том, что вы пользуетесь числовым типом данных с плавающей запятой. Как известно, в этом типе *точно* могут быть представлены лишь те дробные значения, знаменатель которых равен степени двойки. Для вашего числа `9.995` реальное значение — `9.9949999999999992184029906638897955417633056640625`, это ближайшее к вашему число, которое можно выразить в типе данных `double`. У вас получается `l == 4`.

Вот вам маленькая программа на C# (основанная на [коде Джона Скита](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs)), которая показывает, что происходит под капотом числа типа `double`: http://ideone.com/hTiobV#stdout.

---

Что делать? Например, вы можете вводить числа как строки, сами находить вручную часть числа до десятичной точки и часть после, и округлять вручную.

В некоторых языках есть готовый тип данных, работающий с такими числами (например, `decimal` из C# или `java.math.BigDecimal` из Java), для C++ может подойти более сильный `<boost/multiprecision>` (но вам придётся подключать boost).

Comment: http://0.30000000000000004.com

Answer (score 3):

Если необходимо считать копейки и рубли, то правильной идеей является НЕ использовать числа плавающей точкой, а эмулировать числа с фиксированной точкой через целые. Т.е. считать за единицу копейку. Если не хватает разрядов - попробуйте long long int. Если и long long не хватает - пора бы реализовать арифметику bignum. Студенты обычно ее реализуют поверх массивов однабайтных целых (это неэффективно по памяти, но зато познавательно).

Comment: Проблема во вводе, ввод-то с десятичной точкой.

Comment: @VladD ввести строку и преобразовать ее в целое (с учетом возможной точки внутри) - небольшая проблема.

Comment: @andy.37: В том-то и дело, что проблема ТС именно в потере точности при вводе, как мне кажется.

Comment: Согласен с @andy.37 - если включить мозг, то строчку разобрать не проблема. Даже если сделать это врукопашку